# Having problems with my function it has to be able to except a accepts a character ch (i.e., a string of length one) and returns true if ch is a vowel

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

```
function isVowelR(ch,pattern){
var ch = "a";
var pattern =/a|e|i|o|u|y/i ;
}
if(pattern.test(ch)){
return true;        
}
else{return false}
```

I got an error saying that there was an illegal return statement, I also have to keep it as a function with an if else statement.

Comment: You closed the function before your `if` statement.  The `if/else` blocks should be *inside* the function.  Consistently format your code and indent appropriately and you can see issues like this right away.  (Also, your function is ignoring the parameters it receives and just re-defining those same variables again internally.  I doubt you meant to do that.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You closed your function too early. The error is because you had `return` statements that were not contained within a function. See the fixed code below, where I've moved the closing curly brace to be after the `if/else` statement.

```
function isVowelR(ch, pattern) {
    var ch = "a";
    var pattern = /a|e|i|o|u|y/i;

    if (pattern.test(ch)) {
        return true;        
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: As others have pointed out, the parameters are being ignored and overwritten. I suspect this is a more helpful function:

```
function isVowelR(ch) {
    var pattern = /a|e|i|o|u|y/i;

    if (pattern.test(ch)) {
        return true;        
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you overwriting the function arguments? They should be outside me thinks `ch, pattern`

Comment: My GE was trying to help me and told me to do that for some reason

Answer (score 1):

```
    var ch = "a";

    function isVowelR(ch){
      const pattern =/a|e|i|o|u/i;
      return pattern.test(ch);
    }
```